# Ansible - how to parse variable with JSON by local script

Tags: python, json, ansible

I have ansible playbook that at the end gets the logs from the remote device and store them in a variable as JSON structure. I also have a script written in Python that can parse logs written in this JSON and display output that contains specific logs and a text message. This is the last playbook task

I have a problem how to connect it. I tried to use local_action

```
- name: Parse by local script
  local_action: "shell echo '{{ result_VPN_log_json }}' | ./checkit.py"
```

This fails because in JSON there are characters like '('

```
"/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('",
```

Do you know how to fix it or how to use pipes in such cases?
Is the only other way writing own filter plugin and store output of my checkit.py script in another variable in the playbook and then print it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`quote` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id6) to escape characters which are interpreted by shell:

```
- name: Parse by local script
  local_action: "shell echo '{{ result_VPN_log_json | quote }}' | ./checkit.py"
```

<sup>It's impossible however to tell how your script will treat quoted JSON string.</sup>